# Scala Macros: get vals from object

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-macros

I use scala macros for extract all object from package, and then i would like get some values from object:

```
 package example

 trait A {}
 object B extends A { val test = "test" }

 //macro
 object Macro
   def getVals(packageName: String) = macro getValsImpl

   def getValsImpl(c: Context)(packageName: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
     import c.universe._

     val pkg = from.tree match {
      case Literal(Constant(name: String)) => c.mirror.staticPackage(name)
     }

     val objects = pkg.typeSignature.members.collect {
       //get all objects which a subtype of `A`   
       case x if (x.isModule && x.typeSignature <:< typeOf[A]) => x  
     }.toList

     val o = objects(0)

     println(o.test)

     reify {}
   }
 }
```

But i got error

```
value test is not a member of c.universe.ModuleSymbol
```

Comment: I'm completely guessing here, and my scala is not that good, but try checking the size of `objects` or the type of `objects(0)`. Maybe you're getting something other than a B

Comment: This may give you the answers you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128783/how-can-i-get-the-actual-object-referred-to-by-scala-2-10-reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaking compile time artifacts for actual runtime values.

Macro implementation is invoked at compile time. The actual objects you are trying to access don't yet exist (only the language `Symbol`s that represent them). That is why you are getting a `ModuleSymbol` when you expect the `B` object.

In other words, you simply can't access `B` in macro implementation.

Macros are meant to analyze, transform and generate *code* (represented as `Expr`s and `Tree`s). So, what you can do is - having a `ModuleSymbol` that represents an object - generate code that, when compiled and finally executed in runtime, will evaluate to that object. But I don't know if this is what you want here.

Comment: Doesn't the link I posted in the comments suggest you can get an instance of B?

Comment: @MillieSmith No. The link you posted talks about Scala _runtime_ reflection. This question is about macros.