# Custom Scala enum, most elegant version searched

Tags: scala, enums, scala-2.10, scala-macros

For a project of mine I have implemented a Enum based upon

```
trait Enum[A] {
  trait Value { self: A =>
    _values :+= this
  }
  private var _values = List.empty[A]
  def values = _values
}

sealed trait Currency extends Currency.Value
object Currency extends Enum[Currency] {
  case object EUR extends Currency
  case object GBP extends Currency
}
```

from [Case objects vs Enumerations in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898932/case-classes-vs-enumerations-in-scala). I worked quite nice, till I run into the following problem. Case objects seem to be lazy and if I use Currency.value I might actually get an empty List. It would have been possible to make a call against all Enum Values on startup so that the value list would be populated, but that would be kind of defeating the point.

So I ventured into the dark and unknown places of scala reflection and came up with this solution, based upon the following SO answers. [Can I get a compile-time list of all of the case objects which derive from a sealed parent in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078366/can-i-get-a-compile-time-list-of-all-of-the-case-objects-which-derive-from-a-sea)
and [How can I get the actual object referred to by Scala 2.10 reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128783/how-can-i-get-the-actual-object-referred-to-by-scala-2-10-reflection)

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

abstract class Enum[A: TypeTag] {
  trait Value

  private def sealedDescendants: Option[Set[Symbol]] = {
    val symbol = typeOf[A].typeSymbol
    val internal = symbol.asInstanceOf[scala.reflect.internal.Symbols#Symbol]
    if (internal.isSealed)
      Some(internal.sealedDescendants.map(_.asInstanceOf[Symbol]) - symbol)
    else None
  }

  def values = (sealedDescendants getOrElse Set.empty).map(
    symbol => symbol.owner.typeSignature.member(symbol.name.toTermName)).map(
    module => reflect.runtime.currentMirror.reflectModule(module.asModule).instance).map(
    obj => obj.asInstanceOf[A]
  )
}
```

The amazing part of this is that it actually works, but it is ugly as hell and I would be interested if it would be possible to make this simpler and more elegant and to get rid of the asInstanceOf calls.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a simple macro based implementation:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

abstract class Enum[E] {
  def values: Seq[E] = macro Enum.caseObjectsSeqImpl[E]
}

object Enum {
  def caseObjectsSeqImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context) = {
    import c.universe._

    val typeSymbol = weakTypeOf[A].typeSymbol.asClass
    require(typeSymbol.isSealed)
    val subclasses = typeSymbol.knownDirectSubclasses
      .filter(_.asClass.isCaseClass)
      .map(s => Ident(s.companion))
      .toList
    val seqTSymbol = weakTypeOf[Seq[A]].typeSymbol.companion
    c.Expr(Apply(Ident(seqTSymbol), subclasses))
  }
}
```

With this you could then write:

```
sealed trait Currency
object Currency extends Enum[Currency] {
  case object USD extends Currency
  case object EUR extends Currency
}
```

so then

```
Currency.values == Seq(Currency.USD, Currency.EUR)
```

Since it's a macro, the `Seq(Currency.USD, Currency.EUR)` is generated at compile time, rather than runtime. Note, though, that since it's a macro, the definition of the `class Enum` must be in a separate project from where it is used (i.e. the concrete subclasses of `Enum` like `Currency`). This is a relatively simple implementation; you could do more complicated things like traverse multilevel class hierarchies to find more case objects at the cost of greater complexity, but hopefully this will get you started.

Comment: So the error message I get:

macro implementation not found: values (the most common reason for that is that you cannot use macro implementations in the same compilation run that defines them)

Is that I have to create in a separate project then my actual implementation, that's is unfortunate :(

Comment: I will keep this open a little while longer, but I really like your version. I tossed it on https://github.com/wallnuss/scala-utils

Comment: Yeah, the error you got is because the macro has to be in a separate project from where it gets used. While annoying, it's a limitation of how macros are implemented in Scala, so it's something we have to live with for now.

Comment: I run into a problem that I cannot reconstruct reliable...

I added some test to the github project and when you execute sbt clean test almost all of them will fail. When you change NamedEnum to an abstract class instead of a trait the test will suddenly succeed.

Comment: I don't think your issues have anything to do with the trait vs class thing, but are related to the order in which the files get compiled. If you just cause the EnumTest class to be compiled after SimpleEnum, then those tests consistently pass in a clean build. Seems like a compiler bug.

Answer (score 3):

A late answer, but anyways...

As wallnuss said, `knownDirectSubclasses` is unreliable as of writing and has been for quite some time.

I created a small lib called Enumeratum (https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum) that allows you to use case objects as enums in a similar way, but doesn't use `knownDirectSubclasses` and instead looks at the body that encloses the method call to find subclasses. It has proved to be reliable thus far.

Comment: That looks like a nice solution. If it would have been around a year ago it would have saved me a lot of grief.

Answer (score 1):

The article "**[“You don’t need a macro” Except when you do](https://medium.com/@maxaf/you-don-t-need-a-macro-12491d208551#.nopg6l5ai)**" by [Max Afonov
maxaf](https://github.com/maxaf) describes a nice way to use macro for defining enums.

The end-result of that implementation is visible in [`github.com/maxaf/numerato`](https://github.com/maxaf/numerato)

> Simply create a plain class, annotate it with `@enum`, and use the familiar `val ... = Value` declaration to define a few enum values.
>
> The `@enum` annotation invokes a macro, which will:
>
> - Replace your `Status` class with a `sealed Status` class suitable for acting as a base type for enum values. Specifically, it'll grow a `(val index: Int, val name: String)` constructor. These parameters will be supplied by the macro, so you don't have to worry about it.
> - Generate a `Status` companion object, which will contain most of the pieces that now make `Status` an enumeration. This includes a values: `List[Status]`, plus lookup methods.
>
> Give the above `Status enum`, here's what the generated code looks like:

```scala
scala> @enum(debug = true) class Status {
     |   val Enabled, Disabled = Value
     | }
{
  sealed abstract class Status(val index: Int, val name: String)(implicit sealant: Status.Sealant);
  object Status {
    @scala.annotation.implicitNotFound(msg = "Enum types annotated with ".+("@enum can not be extended directly. To add another value to the enum, ").+("please adjust your `def ... = Value` declaration.")) sealed abstract protected class Sealant;
    implicit protected object Sealant extends Sealant;
    case object Enabled extends Status(0, "Enabled") with scala.Product with scala.Serializable;
    case object Disabled extends Status(1, "Disabled") with scala.Product with scala.Serializable;
    val values: List[Status] = List(Enabled, Disabled);
    val fromIndex: _root_.scala.Function1[Int, Status] = Map(Enabled.index.->(Enabled), Disabled.index.->(Disabled));
    val fromName: _root_.scala.Function1[String, Status] = Map(Enabled.name.->(Enabled), Disabled.name.->(Disabled));
    def switch[A](pf: PartialFunction[Status, A]): _root_.scala.Function1[Status, A] = macro numerato.SwitchMacros.switch_impl[Status, A]
  };
  ()
}
defined class Status
defined object Status
```

Comment: Thanks for the plug!