# How to get correct value type when extending Scala Enumeration.Val

Tags: scala, enumeration

While there are many questions on S/O regarding difficulties with Scala Enumeration, I haven't found a question that addresses my problem.  Specifically, I am trying to translate the Planet example from the [Oracle Java enum docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) into the Scala Enumeration idiom so as to better understand the workings and pro's & con's of the Scala form.

My ported code so far appears below and, suffice to say, it does not compile as might be expected from the principle of least surprise.  Apart from type casting with .asInstanceOf, is there a better or accepted solution?

Thanks, Justin

```
    object Planet extends Enumeration {

  // universal gravitational constant (m3 kg-1 s-2)
  val G = 6.67300E-11

  val Mercury = Planet(3.303e+23, 2.4397e6)
  val Venus = Planet(4.869e+24, 6.0518e6)
  val Earth = Planet(5.976e+24, 6.37814e6)
  val Mars = Planet(6.421e+23, 3.3972e6)
  val Jupiter = Planet(1.9e+27, 7.1492e7)
  val Saturn = Planet(5.688e+26, 6.0268e7)
  val Uranus = Planet(8.686e+25, 2.5559e7)
  val Neptune = Planet(1.024e+26, 2.4746e7)

  case class Planet(mass: Double, radius: Double) extends Val {

    def surfaceGravity: Double = G * mass / (radius * radius)

    def surfaceWeight(otherMass: Double) = otherMass * surfaceGravity

  }

}

object PlayEnumeration extends App {


  val earthWeight = 175
  val mass = earthWeight / Planet.Earth.surfaceGravity

  Planet.values.foreach {
    // Does not compile as might be expected.
    // value surfaceWeight is not a member of play.Planet.Value
    p => println(s"Your weight on $p is ${p.surfaceWeight(mass)}")
  }

  println

}
```

Comment: I am tempted to say "Just don't use Scala's Enumeration for this sort of thing."  Scala doesn't have language-supported enums, and although Scala is very expressive, it is not quite expressive enough to capture the full power of Java enums as a library construct.

Comment: You could rewrite `Enumeration` so it takes a type parameter or has a type member to represent the type of the values. This would let you do what you want, but I think it is always better to use case objects than to use `Enumeration`.

Comment: @RexKerr On the other hand, using macros _should_ allow the full power of Java enums (at least, I think so). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089920/custom-scala-enum-most-elegant-version-searched or https://github.com/aloiscochard/enum-paradise

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov - They should, but not in a Java-compatible way without changes to the compiler back end, AFAIK.

Comment: @RexKerr Yes, certainly they won't produce Java enums.

Comment: @RexKerr Surprisingly, it turns out to be possible! https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-language/C7Pm6ab1sPs%5B101-125-false%5D

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov - I'm aware of that!  IIRC there was still one outstanding issue.  Don't remember what, though.  I might just be misremembering.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast enum value to Planet using asInstanceOf[Planet]

```
object PlanetEnum extends Enumeration {

  // universal gravitational constant (m3 kg-1 s-2)
  val G = 6.67300E-11

  val Mercury = Planet(3.303e+23, 2.4397e6)
  val Venus = Planet(4.869e+24, 6.0518e6)
  val Earth = Planet(5.976e+24, 6.37814e6)
  val Mars = Planet(6.421e+23, 3.3972e6)
  val Jupiter = Planet(1.9e+27, 7.1492e7)
  val Saturn = Planet(5.688e+26, 6.0268e7)
  val Uranus = Planet(8.686e+25, 2.5559e7)
  val Neptune = Planet(1.024e+26, 2.4746e7)

  case class Planet(mass: Double, radius: Double) extends Val {

    def surfaceGravity: Double = G * mass / (radius * radius)

    def surfaceWeight(otherMass: Double) = otherMass * surfaceGravity

  }

}

object PlayEnumeration extends App {

  val earthWeight = 175
  val mass = earthWeight / PlanetEnum.Earth.surfaceGravity

  PlanetEnum.values.foreach {
    p => println(s"Your weight on $p is ${p.asInstanceOf[Planet].surfaceWeight(mass)}")

  }

  println

}
```

Comment: I just posted an answer that was essentially the same as yours, only using a Scala implicit so that it "hides" the use of asInstanceOf (which can result in negative points in a code style tool): http://stackoverflow.com/a/25924114/501113

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to `object Planet`:

```
implicit def convert(value: Value): Planet = value.asInstanceOf[Planet]
```

This leverages the extraordinary power of implicits within Scala.

If you are looking for something that might give you even more flexibility (especially exhaustive pattern matching), I just [posted an answer showing my general solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25923651/501113) for enumerations within Scala.

After doing extensive research on options, the solution is a much more complete overview of this domain including solving the "sealed trait + case object" pattern where I finally solved the JVM class/object initialization ordering problem.